# Create an array of deferreds with Q.js

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, q

Using Q and the request modules, I'm trying to push a dynamic number of deferreds into an array, so I can later call Q.all on them. I've read around and below is as close as I can get, but it's not working.

I think I get the Q.all part, but it's how I should be storing each deferred in the array is where I'm getting tripped up.

```
_ = require 'underscore'
request = require 'request'
Q = require 'q'


class Github

  ## Filter issues by "important Label"
  getIssues: (callback) ->

    options ...

    request options, (err, resp, body) =>

      issues = _.filter JSON.parse(body), (issue) ->
         ...

      ## I'm attempting to store my promises in this `deferreds`
      deferreds = @getPulls issues


      ## to test I'm getting something, and I do
      setTimeout ( => console.log @pulls.length ), 2500

      ## but this gives me 0
      Q.all(deferreds).then( (a,b) =>
        console.log 'Q all', @pulls.length
      )


  # Get PR info for important issues
  getPulls: (issues) ->

    deferreds = []
    @pulls = []

    for issue in issues

      options = ...
      deferred = Q.defer()

      deferreds.push request options, (err, resp, body) =>
        @pulls.push JSON.parse body
        deferred.resolve(JSON.parse(body))

        return deferred.promise


    return deferreds



module.exports = Github
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out -

```
class Github

  pulls = []

  getIssues: (callback) ->    

    options = ...
    request options, (err, resp, body) =>

      issues = _.filter JSON.parse(body), (issue) ->
        ....

      @pulls = []
      deferreds = []

      for issue in issues
        d = @makeDeferred issue
        deferreds.push d

      Q.all(deferreds).then( (a,b) =>
        console.log 'Q all done', @pulls.length
      )


  makeDeferred: (issue) ->
    deferred = Q.defer()

    options = ...

    request options, (err, resp, body) =>
      @pulls.push JSON.parse(body)
      deferred.resolve()

    deferred.promise  


module.exports = Github
```